# How do I organize groups of pages in SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, migration, pages

I'm importing content from an old site into SharePoint. The old site was organized kind of like a blog with categories, something like:

- News - 20 pages
- Company A Bulletins - 50 pages
- Company B Bulletins - 50 pages
- Company C Bulletins - 50 pages
- Local Announcements - 40 pages

What's the right way to organize this in SharePoint? I'm considering making a list for each category and putting the content in a 'Multiple lines of text' column. But maybe they should be pages?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a site column of type choice and have following values

- News
- Company A Bulletins
- Company B Bulletins
- Company C Bulletins
- Local Annoucements

Then add this site column to the Pages/SitePage document library.

During migration set the site column value accordingly.